# MKMapView viewForAnnotation not call in iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8, mkmapview, mkmapviewdelegate

MKMapView delegate methods not called in iOS 8.
In viewDidLoad:

```
CGRect mapViewFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 129.0, 320.0, 419.0);
    _mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:mapViewFrame];
    [_mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [_mapView setDelegate:self];
    [_mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
```

These methods are never called:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{};

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {}
```

In previous versions of iOS 8 everything worked.

Comment: Got the same issue!!

Answer (score 0):

I think user location retrieval has changed in iOS 8. Now you need to use CLLocationManager authorisation to track user location. mapView.showsUserLocation = YES is not enough anymore.

You need a CLLocationManager instance:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

In viewDidLoad

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) {
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
// your mapKit stuff...
```

And this should start tracking user's location and call the delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding other annotations (not user location) and seeing if the delegate methods get called? That will help you troubleshoot the problem